# Shellcode Without null bytes

Tags: c, linux, assembly, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am trying to convert an assembly program into null-free shellcode.

However, I am unsure how to go about this for certain instructions. Some of them way more complex than the examples I found in the web.

I used a C program from the web as an example, then converted to .s,using  gcc -Wall -O -fverbose-asm -S example.c
gcc -c example.s -o example.o
gcc  example.o -o example
objdump -d example

```
.file   "test.c"
# GNU C (Debian 4.9.2-10) version 4.9.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
#   compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.2
# GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
# options passed:  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu test.c -mtune=generic
# -march=x86-64 -O -Wall -fverbose-asm
# options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations
# -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg
# -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcommon -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers
# -fdefer-pop -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fdwarf2-cfi-asm
# -fearly-inlining -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fforward-propagate
# -ffunction-cse -fgcse-lm -fgnu-runtime -fgnu-unique 
# -fguess-branch-probability -fident -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2
# -finline -finline-atomics -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-profile
# -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fira-hoist-pressure
# -fira-share-save-slots -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts
# -fkeep-static-consts -fleading-underscore -fmath-errno -fmerge-constants
# -fmerge-debug-strings -fmove-loop-invariants -fomit-frame-pointer
# -fpeephole -fprefetch-loop-arrays -freg-struct-return
# -fsched-critical-path-heuristic -fsched-dep-count-heuristic
# -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock -fsched-last-insn-heuristic
# -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic
# -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fshow-column -fshrink-wrap -fsigned-zeros
# -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller -fsplit-wide-types -fstrict-volatile-bitfields
# -fsync-libcalls -ftoplevel-reorder -ftrapping-math -ftree-bit-ccp
# -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-copy-prop
# -ftree-copyrename -ftree-cselim -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts
# -ftree-dse -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-loop-if-convert
# -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon -ftree-loop-optimize
# -ftree-parallelize-loops= -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-reassoc
# -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-ter
# -funit-at-a-time -funwind-tables -fverbose-asm -fzero-initialized-in-bss
# -m128bit-long-double -m64 -m80387 -malign-stringops
# -mavx256-split-unaligned-load -mavx256-split-unaligned-store
# -mfancy-math-387 -mfp-ret-in-387 -mfxsr -mglibc -mieee-fp
# -mlong-double-80 -mmmx -mno-sse4 -mpush-args -mred-zone -msse -msse2
# -mtls-direct-seg-refs

.section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
.string "Could not create socket"
.LC1:
.string "127.0.0.1"
.LC2:
.string "connect error"
.LC3:
.string "Connected\n"
.section    .rodata.str1.8,"aMS",@progbits,1
.align 8
.LC4:
.string "Hola Redon , I really appreaciate your help\n\r\n"
.section    .rodata.str1.1
.LC5:
.string "Send failed"
.LC6:
.string "Data Send\n"
.LC7:
.string "recv failed"
.LC8:
.string "Reply received\n"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
 main:
.LFB29:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbx    #
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 3, -16
subq    $2016, %rsp #,
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 2032
movl    $0, %edx    #,
movl    $1, %esi    #,
movl    $2, %edi    #,
call    socket  #
movl    %eax, %ebx  #, socket_desc
cmpl    $-1, %eax   #, socket_desc
jne .L2 #,
movl    $.LC0, %edi #,
movl    $0, %eax    #,
call    printf  #
.L2:
movl    $.LC1, %edi #,
call    inet_addr   #
movl    %eax, 2004(%rsp)    # D.3169, server.sin_addr.s_addr
movw    $2, 2000(%rsp)  #, server.sin_family
movw    $14093, 2002(%rsp)  #, server.sin_port
movl    $16, %edx   #,
leaq    2000(%rsp), %rsi    #, tmp96
movl    %ebx, %edi  # socket_desc,
call    connect #
testl   %eax, %eax  # D.3168
jns .L3 #,
movl    $.LC2, %edi #,
call    puts    #
movl    $1, %eax    #, D.3168
jmp .L4 #
.L3:
movl    $.LC3, %edi #,
call    puts    #
movl    $0, %ecx    #,
movl    $46, %edx   #,
movl    $.LC4, %esi #,
movl    %ebx, %edi  # socket_desc,
call    send    #
testq   %rax, %rax  # D.3170
jns .L5 #,
movl    $.LC5, %edi #,
call    puts    #
movl    $1, %eax    #, D.3168
jmp .L4 #
.L5:
movl    $.LC6, %edi #,
call    puts    #
movl    $0, %ecx    #,
movl    $2000, %edx #,
movq    %rsp, %rsi  #,
movl    %ebx, %edi  # socket_desc,
call    recv    #
testq   %rax, %rax  # D.3170
jns .L6 #,
movl    $.LC7, %edi #,
call    puts    #
.L6:
movl    $.LC8, %edi #,
call    puts    #
movq    %rsp, %rdi  #,
call    puts    #
movl    $0, %eax    #, D.3168
.L4:
addq    $2016, %rsp #,
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
popq    %rbx    #
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE29:
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Wich give this:

```
 test:     file format elf64-x86-64


 Disassembly of section .init:

 0000000000400500 <_init>:
 400500:    48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 400504:    48 8b 05 fd 06 20 00    mov      0x2006fd(%rip),%rax        # 600c08 <_DYNAMIC+0x1d0>
 40050b:    48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 40050e:    74 05                   je     400515 <_init+0x15>
 400510:    e8 7b 00 00 00          callq  400590 <__gmon_start__@plt>
 400515:    48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 400519:    c3                      retq   

 Disassembly of section .plt:

 0000000000400520 <recv@plt-0x10>:
 400520:    ff 35 f2 06 20 00       pushq  0x2006f2(%rip)        # 600c18 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 400526:    ff 25 f4 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006f4(%rip)        # 600c20 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
 40052c:    0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

 0000000000400530 <recv@plt>:
 400530:    ff 25 f2 06 20 00       jmpq        *0x2006f2(%rip)        # 600c28 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x18>
 400536:    68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
 40053b:    e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 0000000000400540 <puts@plt>:
 400540:    ff 25 ea 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006ea(%rip)        # 600c30 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x20>
 400546:    68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
 40054b:    e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 0000000000400550 <send@plt>:
 400550:    ff 25 e2 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006e2(%rip)        # 600c38 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x28>
 400556:    68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
 40055b:    e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 0000000000400560 <printf@plt>:
 400560:    ff 25 da 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006da(%rip)        # 600c40 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x30>
 400566:    68 03 00 00 00          pushq  $0x3
 40056b:    e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 0000000000400570 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
 400570:    ff 25 d2 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006d2(%rip)        # 600c48 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x38>
 400576:    68 04 00 00 00          pushq  $0x4
 40057b:    e9 a0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 0000000000400580 <inet_addr@plt>:
 400580:    ff 25 ca 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006ca(%rip)        # 600c50 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x40>
 400586:    68 05 00 00 00          pushq  $0x5
 40058b:    e9 90 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 0000000000400590 <__gmon_start__@plt>:
 400590:    ff 25 c2 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006c2(%rip)        # 600c58 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x48>
 400596:    68 06 00 00 00          pushq  $0x6
 40059b:    e9 80 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 00000000004005a0 <connect@plt>:
 4005a0:    ff 25 ba 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006ba(%rip)        # 600c60 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x50>
 4005a6:    68 07 00 00 00          pushq  $0x7
 4005ab:    e9 70 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

 00000000004005b0 <socket@plt>:
  4005b0:   ff 25 b2 06 20 00       jmpq   *0x2006b2(%rip)        # 600c68 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x58>
  4005b6:   68 08 00 00 00          pushq  $0x8
  4005bb:   e9 60 ff ff ff          jmpq   400520 <_init+0x20>

  Disassembly of section .text:

  00000000004005c0 <_start>:
  4005c0:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  4005c2:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  4005c5:   5e                      pop    %rsi
  4005c6:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  4005c9:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  4005cd:   50                      push   %rax
  4005ce:   54                      push   %rsp
  4005cf:   49 c7 c0 30 08 40 00    mov    $0x400830,%r8
  4005d6:   48 c7 c1 c0 07 40 00    mov    $0x4007c0,%rcx
  4005dd:   48 c7 c7 b6 06 40 00    mov    $0x4006b6,%rdi
  4005e4:   e8 87 ff ff ff          callq  400570    <__libc_start_main@plt>
  4005e9:   f4                      hlt    
  4005ea:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

  00000000004005f0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
  4005f0:   b8 87 0c 60 00          mov    $0x600c87,%eax
  4005f5:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005f6:   48 2d 80 0c 60 00       sub    $0x600c80,%rax
  4005fc:   48 83 f8 0e             cmp    $0xe,%rax
  400600:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400603:   76 1b                   jbe    400620 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
  400605:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40060a:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  40060d:   74 11                   je     400620 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
  40060f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400610:   bf 80 0c 60 00          mov    $0x600c80,%edi
  400615:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
  400617:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40061e:   00 00 
  400620:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400621:   c3                      retq   
  400622:   66 66 66 66 66 2e 0f    data16 data16 data16 data16  nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400629:   1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 

  0000000000400630 <register_tm_clones>:
  400630:   be 80 0c 60 00          mov    $0x600c80,%esi
  400635:   55                      push   %rbp
  400636:   48 81 ee 80 0c 60 00    sub    $0x600c80,%rsi
  40063d:   48 c1 fe 03             sar    $0x3,%rsi
  400641:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400644:   48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
  400647:   48 c1 e8 3f             shr    $0x3f,%rax
  40064b:   48 01 c6                add    %rax,%rsi
  40064e:   48 d1 fe                sar    %rsi
  400651:   74 15                   je     400668    <register_tm_clones+0x38>
  400653:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400658:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  40065b:   74 0b                   je     400668 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
  40065d:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40065e:   bf 80 0c 60 00          mov    $0x600c80,%edi
  400663:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
  400665:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  400668:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400669:   c3                      retq   
  40066a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

  0000000000400670 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
  400670:   80 3d 09 06 20 00 00    cmpb       $0x0,0x200609(%rip)        # 600c80 <__TMC_END__>
  400677:   75 11                   jne    40068a <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x1a>
  400679:   55                      push   %rbp
  40067a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40067d:   e8 6e ff ff ff          callq  4005f0 <deregister_tm_clones>
  400682:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400683:   c6 05 f6 05 20 00 01    movb     $0x1,0x2005f6(%rip)        # 600c80 <__TMC_END__>
  40068a:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
  40068c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

  0000000000400690 <frame_dummy>:
  400690:   bf 30 0a 60 00          mov    $0x600a30,%edi
  400695:   48 83 3f 00             cmpq   $0x0,(%rdi)
  400699:   75 05                   jne    4006a0     <frame_dummy+0x10>
  40069b:   eb 93                   jmp    400630   <register_tm_clones>
  40069d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  4006a0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4006a5:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4006a8:   74 f1                   je     40069b  <frame_dummy+0xb>
  4006aa:   55                      push   %rbp
  4006ab:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4006ae:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
  4006b0:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4006b1:   e9 7a ff ff ff          jmpq   400630  <register_tm_clones>

  00000000004006b6 <main>:
  4006b6:   53                      push   %rbx
  4006b7:   48 81 ec e0 07 00 00    sub    $0x7e0,%rsp
  4006be:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  4006c3:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
  4006c8:   bf 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edi
  4006cd:   e8 de fe ff ff          callq  4005b0 <socket@plt>
  4006d2:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
  4006d4:   83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
  4006d7:   75 0f                   jne    4006e8 <main+0x32>
  4006d9:   bf 44 08 40 00          mov    $0x400844,%edi
  4006de:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4006e3:   e8 78 fe ff ff          callq  400560 <printf@plt>
  4006e8:   bf 5c 08 40 00          mov    $0x40085c,%edi
  4006ed:   e8 8e fe ff ff          callq  400580 <inet_addr@plt>
  4006f2:   89 84 24 d4 07 00 00    mov    %eax,0x7d4(%rsp)
  4006f9:   66 c7 84 24 d0 07 00    movw   $0x2,0x7d0(%rsp)
  400700:   00 02 00 
  400703:   66 c7 84 24 d2 07 00    movw   $0x370d,0x7d2(%rsp)
  40070a:   00 0d 37 
  40070d:   ba 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%edx
  400712:   48 8d b4 24 d0 07 00    lea    0x7d0(%rsp),%rsi
  400719:   00 
  40071a:   89 df                   mov    %ebx,%edi
  40071c:   e8 7f fe ff ff          callq  4005a0 <connect@plt>
  400721:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  400723:   79 11                   jns    400736 <main+0x80>
  400725:   bf 66 08 40 00          mov    $0x400866,%edi
  40072a:   e8 11 fe ff ff          callq  400540 <puts@plt>
  40072f:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  400734:   eb 7a                   jmp    4007b0 <main+0xfa>
  400736:   bf 74 08 40 00          mov    $0x400874,%edi
  40073b:   e8 00 fe ff ff          callq  400540 <puts@plt>
  400740:   b9 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ecx
  400745:   ba 2e 00 00 00          mov    $0x2e,%edx
  40074a:   be b8 08 40 00          mov    $0x4008b8,%esi
  40074f:   89 df                   mov    %ebx,%edi
  400751:   e8 fa fd ff ff          callq  400550 <send@plt>
  400756:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  400759:   79 11                   jns    40076c <main+0xb6>
  40075b:   bf 7f 08 40 00          mov    $0x40087f,%edi
  400760:   e8 db fd ff ff          callq  400540 <puts@plt>
  400765:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40076a:   eb 44                   jmp    4007b0 <main+0xfa>
  40076c:   bf 8b 08 40 00          mov    $0x40088b,%edi
  400771:   e8 ca fd ff ff          callq  400540 <puts@plt>
  400776:   b9 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ecx
  40077b:   ba d0 07 00 00          mov    $0x7d0,%edx
  400780:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  400783:   89 df                   mov    %ebx,%edi
  400785:   e8 a6 fd ff ff          callq  400530 <recv@plt>
  40078a:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  40078d:   79 0a                   jns    400799 <main+0xe3>
  40078f:   bf 96 08 40 00          mov    $0x400896,%edi
  400794:   e8 a7 fd ff ff          callq  400540 <puts@plt>
  400799:   bf a2 08 40 00          mov    $0x4008a2,%edi
  40079e:   e8 9d fd ff ff          callq  400540 <puts@plt>
  4007a3:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  4007a6:   e8 95 fd ff ff          callq  400540 <puts@plt>
  4007ab:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4007b0:   48 81 c4 e0 07 00 00    add    $0x7e0,%rsp
  4007b7:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  4007b8:   c3                      retq   
  4007b9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

  00000000004007c0 <__libc_csu_init>:
  4007c0:   41 57                   push   %r15
  4007c2:   41 89 ff                mov    %edi,%r15d
  4007c5:   41 56                   push   %r14
  4007c7:   49 89 f6                mov    %rsi,%r14
  4007ca:   41 55                   push   %r13
  4007cc:   49 89 d5                mov    %rdx,%r13
  4007cf:   41 54                   push   %r12
  4007d1:   4c 8d 25 48 02 20 00    lea       0x200248(%rip),%r12        # 600a20 <__frame_dummy_init_array_entry>
  4007d8:   55                      push   %rbp
  4007d9:   48 8d 2d 48 02 20 00    lea    0x200248(%rip),%rbp        # 600a28 <__init_array_end>
  4007e0:   53                      push   %rbx
  4007e1:   4c 29 e5                sub    %r12,%rbp
  4007e4:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  4007e6:   48 c1 fd 03             sar    $0x3,%rbp
  4007ea:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4007ee:   e8 0d fd ff ff          callq  400500 <_init>
  4007f3:   48 85 ed                test   %rbp,%rbp
  4007f6:   74 1e                   je     400816 <__libc_csu_init+0x56>
  4007f8:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4007ff:   00 
  400800:   4c 89 ea                mov    %r13,%rdx
  400803:   4c 89 f6                mov    %r14,%rsi
  400806:   44 89 ff                mov    %r15d,%edi
  400809:   41 ff 14 dc             callq  *(%r12,%rbx,8)
  40080d:   48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
  400811:   48 39 eb                cmp    %rbp,%rbx
  400814:   75 ea                   jne    400800  <__libc_csu_init+0x40>
  400816:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  40081a:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  40081b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40081c:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
  40081e:   41 5d                   pop    %r13
  400820:   41 5e                   pop    %r14
  400822:   41 5f                   pop    %r15
  400824:   c3                      retq   
  400825:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 nopw  %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40082c:   00 00 00 00 

0000000000400830 <__libc_csu_fini>:
 400830:    f3 c3                   repz retq 

 Disassembly of section .fini:

 0000000000400834 <_fini>:
 400834:    48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 400838:    48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 40083c:    c3                      retq
```

As you can see it´s a lot .... First question would be... null bytes from my .init and .plt seccion will affect my shellcode or just only the ones in my .text Section?.

I know for example in a case where I have :
 ba 00 00 00 00         mov    $0x0,%edx **I can apply xor %edx,edx**
 b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax,  **can apply xor %eax,eax aswell?**

but what about the cases like :
ff 35 f2 06 20 00       pushq  0x2006f2(%rip) or
66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

Since Im a newbie who wants to learn any help would be appreciate, Yes I have read Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit but english is not my mother language and like I said Im a newbie so not everything is clear for me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `mov $0x1, %eax` -> `xor %eax, %eax; inc %eax`

Comment: We can't list every possibility for you. Don't get me wrong, but it looks like you are missing basic asm knowledge required for this task, and SO is not the place to get that knowledge. (I mean, you didn't even recognize a `NOP` instruction.) Do some more learning and come back when you have a specific question we can answer. PS: you disassembled a whole lot of C library code there.